# Monotouch binding for ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat

Tags: iphone, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios

In Monotouch the only way you can get the Image from an ABPerson instance is using the Image property which returns the image in its original size.

In Objective-C there is a function called ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat), which can return the thumbnailed image from the contact, 
but Monotouch does not provide a binding for this.

Does any body know how to call this function in Monotouch or how to create its binding?

Thanks,
Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution (by disassemling the monotouch.dll and look carefully at the internal code)

```
[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook")]
private static extern IntPtr ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(IntPtr handle, ABPersonImageFormat format);

ABPersonImageFormat format = ABPersonImageFormat.Thumbnail;
NSData data = new NSData(ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person.Handle, format));
UIImage imgThumb = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
```

Good luck with it !!!

Answer (score 0):

It's bound as `MonoTouch.AddressBook.ABPerson.CopyImage (ABPersonImageFormat format);`

Comment: Is it? I can't find it anywhere. Check documentation: http://docs.go-mono.com/MonoTouch.AddressBook.ABPerson/Members#methods

Comment: I'll have to recheck. It might just be that CopyImage (format) exists only in Xamarin's "MonoTouch" - if so, I might argue to rename it to GetImage(format). FWIW, I work at Xamarin and am working on the replacement for MonoTouch so I've casually been going through StackOverflow to find ways to improve on the old MonoTouch.